# Auto Focus Property is not working in Text Input Component on React Native

Tags: react-native, search, keyboard, textinput, autofocus

I am making a Search Bar and I want they keyboard to open up once the Search button has been clicked however the autoFocus property of the TextInput is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
const SearchBar = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Search"
                style={{ width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: 50, borderWidth: 1, 
                borderRadius: 20 }}
                autoFocus={true} 
            /> 
        </View>
     )
}

const Search = () => {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>Keyboard.dismiss()} >
            <SearchBar />
       </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

umm, ideally autoFocus should work on mounting of this comp.

If its not, workaround would be explicitly adding a ref and focusing it

```
class ABC extends .. {

constructor(props){
...
this.textInput = React.createRef();

}

componentDidMount(){
this.textInput.current.focus();
}

 SearchBar = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Search"
                style={{ width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: 50, borderWidth: 1, 
                borderRadius: 20 }}
                autoFocus={true} 
ref={this.textInput}
            /> 
        </View>
     )
}

}
```