# React-Native keyboard autoFocus issue after first opening

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, autofocus, react-native-textinput

I want to make a to-do app for learn React-Native. I added an add button for new tasks. When you push the button, add button is hide and textInput, save button are show. In here, keyboard focus has to automatic. So, I opened autofocus but it is doesn't work when first push the button. AutoFocus works except first push. I am so sory for my bad English. (I run app on my android device)

**App.js codes:**

```
import React from "react"; 
 import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList} from "react-native"; 
 import Add from "./components/add/add" 
  
 function App() { 
   return( 
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
       <FlatList 
         ListHeaderComponent={ 
           <View style={styles.top_container}> 
             <Text style={styles.title}>To-Do</Text> 
             <Text style={styles.count}>0</Text> 
           </View> 
         } 
         /> 
       <Add/> 
     </SafeAreaView> 
   ); 
 }; 
  
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
   container:{ 
     flex:1, 
     backgroundColor:"#102027" 
   }, 
   title:{ 
     color:"#FFA500", 
     fontSize:30, 
     fontWeight:"bold" 
   }, 
   top_container:{ 
     flexDirection:"row", 
     padding:20, 
     justifyContent:"space-between" 
   }, 
   count:{ 
     color:"#FFA500", 
     fontSize:30, 
     fontWeight:"bold", 
   }, 
 }) 
  
 export default App;
```

**add.js codes :**

```
import React from "react"; 
 import {useEffect ,useState} from "react"; 
 import {View, TouchableOpacity, Image, TextInput, Text, TouchableHighlight} from "react-native"; 
 import styles from "./add.style" 
  
 function Add() { 
  
     const [add_mode_as_btn, set_add_mode_as_btn] = useState(true); 
  
     return( 
         <View>{add_mode_as_btn==true? 
             <View style={styles.add_btn_container}> 
                 <TouchableHighlight 
                 onPress={() => {set_add_mode_as_btn(false)}} 
                 style={styles.add_btn}> 
                 <Image style={styles.add_btn_image} source={require('./icons/add.png')}/> 
                 </TouchableHighlight> 
             </View> 
             : 
             <View style={styles.save_container}> 
                 <TextInput  autoFocus={true} style={styles.save_text_input} placeholder="Add Task" placeholderTextColor={"#808080"}/> 
                 <TouchableOpacity  
                     style={styles.save_btn} 
                     onPress={() => set_add_mode_as_btn(true)} 
                      
                     > 
                     <Text style={{color:"white", fontSize:20, fontWeight:"bold"}}>Save</Text> 
                 </TouchableOpacity> 
             </View> 
             } 
         </View> 
     ); 
 }; 
  
 export default Add;
```

**add.style.js codes:**

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"; 
  
 export default StyleSheet.create({ 
     add_btn_container:{ 
         alignItems:"center" 
       }, 
     add_btn:{ 
         width: 45, 
         height: 45, 
         padding: 10, 
         borderRadius: 100, 
         backgroundColor: "#FFA500", 
         marginBottom:10, 
       }, 
     add_btn_image: { 
         width: 25, 
         height: 25, 
         color:"white" 
       }, 
     save_container:{ 
       backgroundColor:"#37474f", 
       margin:10, 
       padding:10, 
       alignItems:"stretch", 
       borderRadius:15 
     }, 
     save_btn:{ 
       backgroundColor:"#FFA500", 
       borderRadius:15, 
       padding:10, 
       alignItems:"center", 
       marginTop:10, 
         
     }, 
     save_text_input:{ 
       borderBottomWidth:2, 
       color:"white", 
       borderBottomColor:"#78909C" 
  
     } 
 })
```

Comment: You can use ref for focus like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68752187/8196025).